# Use student visa to visit another country even after deciding not to pursue studies abroad

Tags: germany, student-visa, schengen

I recently got a student visa to go study a Master's in Germany, however, I decided to take a job instead and never really enrolled in the university (so no student ID in case it matters). However, I want to visit a Schengen country as a tourist and am wondering if I can use my student visa to enter the country. Would I be allowed entry to the other Schengen country given that I decided not to pursue the Master's and never went to Germany in the first place?

Comment: Do you mean to ask whether your student visa is legally valid even though you aren't a student, or does "allowed entry" mean "allowed by the border officer to clear passport control" without regard to the validity of the visa?

Comment: If you never fully enrolled it’s highly likely your visa is no longer valid. The university would typically be required to inform Immigration of your failure to enrol and the Student Visa would then be cancelled/curtailed. If they give a notice period after which the visa is cancelled, in general you would not be allowed to use the visa to travel in and out.

Comment: It might be a good idea to write a letter to the embassy and get an official answer. Technically, the chance that something will go wrong **during** the trip is quite low, but personally I do not like evaluating chances;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would I be allowed entry to the other Schengen country given that I decided not to pursue the Master's and never went to Germany in the first place?

No, you would not. You wouldn't be allowed entry to Germany either. Your visa is for a specific purpose, which is not tourism.

Comment: Downwote for claiming "you wouldn't be allowed entry to Germany either". If German border control can't read thoughts/mind, there is no reason for declining entry to Germany until the travelling person claims different reason for the trip him-/herself

Comment: @AndreySapegin but.. the person *is* claiming a different reason. Quote: "*However, I want to visit a Schengen country as a tourist*".

Comment: Yes, but he is claiming it here and not in front of border control:)

Comment: @AndreySapegin Are you suggesting he should lie to the border control? Have you read Traveller's comment to the question?